# python stops responding when i try to return a list

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/336Pt.jpg)I am using a helper function to read in a file, take each row and put it in a dictionary. Each dictionary must be put into a list then returned. Everytime i try to return the list, python stops responding

```
def readData(filename='steak-risk-survey.csv', fields=fields, values=values):
def helper(row, header):
    b = {header[i]: row[i] for i in range(len(header))}
    return b
list1 = []
with open(filename) as csvDataFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
    row1 = next(csvReader)
    row = next(csvReader)
    for row in csvReader:
        list1.append(helper(row, row1))  
    return list1
```

This is the file the default argument references

Comment: Please provide some example input as well as what you are calling this function with.

Comment: As your code is formatted right now, you have a return statement outside of a function. Please correct your formatting.

Comment: `list1.append(helper(row, row1))`.

Comment: Describe what happens.  This function will never run unless the file is empty, in which case it will return an empty list.  Otherwise the first time through the loop, counter is 0 and `list1` is empty.  The statement `list1[counter]=...` will fail, and you will get a traceback informing you of the error. To add stuff to the list, use the `append` function.

Comment: I changed the function so it utilized list1.append(). when I run the function, the REPL stops responding.